# Как использовать псевдонимы импортов во всём проекте?

Tags: typescript, angular, webstorm, code-style

Проект на ангуляре 11, IDE Webstorm, сделал псевдонимы для импортов, единственный вопрос - где *Fix all 'Imports can be shortened' problems in project*  ?
Или мне придётся в каждый файл заходить и руками исправлять импорты?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете запустить **Inspect Code...** из контекстного меню проекта или папки и в  **Problems** view выбрать соответствующий quick fix:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]